# open external links in mobile safari from a link inside inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, safari, cordova-3

ok so I have simple phonegap 3.2 app and I'm opening a page using the inappbrowser plugin, inside the `receivedEvent` method I have:

```
var ref = window.open('urlxxxxx', '_blank', 'location=no,presentationstyle=fullscreen,toolbar=no');
```

the loaded page has some links, what I need to do is to open those links not in the inappbrowser but in mobile safari, I had already try:

```
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_system">link 7</a>
<a href="http://yahoo.com" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_system'); return false;">link 3</a>
```

but all of them opens inside the inappbrowser, how can I open them in safari?? thanks for any help

oh and also I have tried changing '_blank' to '_self' in the window.open function and nothing, same  result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It worked for me.  I'm using Phonegap Build and jQuery Mobile.

*Note - I tried several other ways of adding attributes directly to the anchor tags e.g. `<a href="http://externalsite.com target="_blank" data-rel="external" data-ajax="false">` also tried `target="_system` - but none worked, so I had to use javascript (only 5 lines though).

It's not too complicated but I'll walk you through it...

1. You need to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag. So somehow grab onto the a tags you care about.  I added a class called "external" to all the anchor tags I wanted to open externally.  Pretty standard stuff:

   ```
   $(document).on('click', ".external", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
   };
   ```
2. Then grab the `href` value from the anchor you're trying to load in safari. Again, nothing too fancy added here:

   ```
   $(document).on('click', ".external", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var targetURL = $(this).attr("href");
   };
   ```
3. This was the bit that took some digging - I guess Phonegap changed their method on this with 2.3? Anyway, open the grabbed `href` in a new window (here is where `"_system"` comes in):

   ```
   $(document).on('click', ".external", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var targetURL = $(this).attr("href");

       window.open(targetURL, "_system");
   });
   ```

That's it. At least that's what worked for me.

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, even when I add a script reference to cordova.js to get support for window.open(..., '_system').  window.open just doesn't seem to work from within an InAppBrowser.